# Port forwarding troubleshooting

Tags: port-forwarding

I am not able to port forward on my Asus GT-AC5300.

This is what I have [edit: new image]:

[image]
[image]

It worked on my previous Netgear router in same house with same setup otherwise.

Googling solutions, getting desperate. Can anyone help troubleshoot?

Comment: I usually configure an internal port too, and you need to have something listening on the internal IP, could add to your post `netstat -anutp | grep 28015` (linux) or `netstat -n | findstr 28015` (windows) if 28015 is the internal port where you expect the data.

Comment: What would be the internal port in my case?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to set up a server for the game Rust, which worked without any problems with my previous more basic router (Netgear), for some reason it does not work on the ASUS. I have edited the original post with the actual settings for Rust.

Comment: looked up Rust, so you need to forward TCP:28015-28016 to internal IP same ports, and the same for UDP. so if your router accepts a range you need to put the ports into from to and select the same ports on the internal side. if your router accepts only a single port you need to create 4 rules, 2 for TCP (one port each) and same for UDP. set external and internal ports to same value, have the rust server running and test again after you applied the settings to the router.

Comment: @Zina thanks! I now have this config https://imgur.com/a/3JbR61y Still not working, though. Ports are closed when checked.

Comment: is your WIndows Rust server listening on those ports? see my first comment how to check. if the receiving internal IP is not listening on the port (or the firewall is not open on that IP) you will not get the port is open result. and please add changes to the original post